# Use linux prompt to make a select on mysql database that shows the value WITHOUT the table graphical rapresentation

Tags: mysql, linux, select, prompt

I need to interact with MySQL database from the linux prompt.
When I write a select (i.e. mysql -u root -e "select count(*) from mytable") I obtain a "graphical representation" of the table with the desired value (the rows count) like this:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       25 |   
+----------+
```

Is there a manner to obtain just the value without the table representation?

Example

```
mysql -u root -e "select count(*) from mytable"
25
```

Comment: I suspect you want this so you can call this from a parent process and parse this more easily. If that is the case, it is probably easier to use one of the mysql connectors: http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-s` option to remove the graphical frames, use the `-N` option to also remove the column headers:

```
mysql -u root -s -N -e "select count(*) from mytable"
```

Comment: It does exactly what I want! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `--silent` or, equivalently, `-s`. From `man mysql`:

> **--silent, -s**
>
> Silent mode. Produce less output. This option can be given multiple
>   times to produce less and less output.
>
> This option results in nontabular output format and escaping of
>   special characters. Escaping may be disabled by using raw mode; see
>   the description for the --raw option.

Note you can use `--html`:

> **--html, -H**
>
> Produce HTML output.

#### Test

```
$ mysql -uXXX -pYYY ZZZ -e "DESC mytable"
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| info         | varchar(64)  | YES  |     |         |                |
| name         | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| important    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| timestamp    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

$ mysql -s -uXXX -pYYY ZZZ -e "DESC mytable"
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
info        varchar(64) YES         
name        varchar(32) NO      NULL    
important   tinyint(1)  NO      0   
timestamp   datetime    NO      NULL    

$ mysql --html -s -uXXX -pYYY ZZZ -e "DESC mytable"
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>Field</TH><TH>Type</TH><TH>Null</TH><TH>Key</TH><TH>Default</TH><TH>Extra</TH></TR><TR><TD>id</TD><TD>int(11)</TD><TD>NO</TD><TD>PRI</TD><TD>NULL</TD><TD>auto_increment</TD></TR><TR><TD>info</TD><TD>varchar(64)</TD><TD>YES</TD><TD></TD><TD></TD><TD></TD></TR><TR><TD>name</TD><TD>varchar(32)</TD><TD>NO</TD><TD></TD><TD>NULL</TD><TD></TD></TR><TR><TD>important</TD><TD>tinyint(1)</TD><TD>NO</TD><TD></TD><TD>0</TD><TD></TD></TR><TR><TD>timestamp</TD><TD>datetime</TD><TD>NO</TD><TD></TD><TD>NULL</TD><TD></TD></TR></TABLE>
```